# How to get tomato-like features on modern wifi hub?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, openwrt, tomato

I used to run tomato (shibby) on an asus wifi router, and it was great. I could:

- -- Run scripts on a schedule to modify iptables (e.g. block facebook at certain hours)
- -- Regulate bandwidth on a per MAC basis (to keep kids from spending their lives streaming video)
- -- Block certain ports, at times, or all the time
- -- Run other scripts on schedule

I am trying to achieve the same functionality with a modern router (currently trying the netgear R6300), and having no joy so far.

**The question is**: What is a modern hardware/software combination that can achieve the above? (preferably in a wifi router, not in a pc based solution!)

(originally tried to ask this on thread: https://superuser.com/q/659462/15466 )

Comment: I think you're missing the reason it closed - product recommendations are off topic for SU in general. I'd guess if you want tomato's features, you're just going to have to look at their HCL and get a suitable one. Another alternative might be openwrt, assuming your model is supported. DD WRT definately seems to have a port for your model. So.. what have you looked at so far?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Sorry, I guess I am missing something. I am trying to figure out how to do something, and to do that something requires specific software (and then the hardware to run that software). What is the right stackexchange site to ask "what software does ____?" (Since this is for a "home" application, I thought SU would be the right place.)

Comment: this question is ok to me - note the lack of closevotes - I'm wondering though, if you've looked at specific alternate firmware yourself . I'm just directing you (or other folk who might be looking for an answer to this) at possible points of reference, since your solution is very likely to be router-centric.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have spent hours and hours on this. No clear path forward with recent hardware. Ergo my question to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Stock firmware on consumer routers is generally not as versatile as DD-WRT or Tomato.  You won't have many of the features available via DD-WRT or Tomato without buying a business-class "VPN" router.

Are you upgrading the router simply to upgrade your wireless to a higher standard such as n or ac?

Configure the new router where routing (if possible) is disabled, and DHCP.  Configure the new router's wireless with an SSID and other parameters as you need.  Then, disable the wireless on the box you have Tomato installed on.

Connect LAN port of new router to a LAN port on the Tomato box.

Essentially, you will put the wireless-access-point only device behind the Tomato box, and you may still be able to manage nodes connected to it.

I'm not sure if the Asus LAN ports are gigabit - if it's 10/100, you might not be able to fully utilize the bandwidth ac provides under optimum conditions, but it sounds like you mostly want to limit Internet bandwidth anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I assume by Tomato you are referring to DD-WRT. It does everything you are mentioned I believe.
Since the post above says no recommending hardware I would suggest going to newegg or your favorite computer hardware shop and search the term "wireless router DD-WRT"

You should be presented with an array of devices where it is either supported or is pre-installed.

At that point simply use common sense and reviews to narrow down the best device for you.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, FYI there are more custom firmwares for routers then just DD-WRT, [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_(firmware)) is one of the more popular, I would suggesting doing a google search before making assumptions

Comment: It seems that active maintenance of tomato is over. There seems to be very little support out there for it.

Comment: Mike: Tomato is tomato, and dd-wrt is dd-wrt. They are both great. Historically, Tomato has had a much easier to use web management. (This was for sure true 1-2 years ago.) But from what I can tell, the tomato world is no longer under active development.

Comment: I see, I had a revision of DD-WRT that was codenamed 'Tomato', hence my confusion. So what are you actually asking then? Just what is a specific router that has open source software already pre-built?

Comment: @SamJones, Yes, unfortunately it's no longer maintained. Unfortunately, it still works better than bleeding edge DD-WRT for some routers. I have a Cisco E3200 that DD-WRT still runs horribly on, and still doesn't support 5GHz wireless, but the 4 year old Tomato firmware runs great on it. There are still some forks floating around under active development.